# Converter um arquivo txt em numero inteiros. Python

Tags: python

Bom dia. Sou um iniciante em linguagem Python, utilizo em Windows 8.1, id Pycharm, versão 3.6.4. A princípio abrir o arquivo não tem sido o problema, antes, converte-lo para número inteiro. Somente assim poderei estabelecer os filtros pretendidos. Comecei ver os modelos da biblioteca pandas para abertura mas não era bem o que preciso.

```
arquivo = open('jogos.txt', 'r')
# EXEMPLO DO ARQUIVO: 1600 (11/02/2014) 50 56 10 35 30 21 20 58
                    # 1610 (10/03/2014) 02 12 11 54 35 36 60 55
# vários sorteios até 1620 (20/04/2014) 40 15 12 17 25 51 38 24
# E como converter de strings para números inteiros.

for linha in arquivo:
    print(linha)
arquivo.close()
# E depois pode selecionar o sorteios desejados, para estabelecer que tipo de  filtros quero aplicar.
```

Comment: Thanks, NoobSaibot pelas correções.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Para formatar o código, você pode selecionar o código todo e apertar o atalho `CTRL+K` ou clicar no botão `{}` no editor. Faça o [tour] para saber como funciona o site, caso necessite de ajudar, você pode acessar a [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá

```
arquivo = open('jogos.txt', 'r')

#Vou armazenar os dados aqui
dados = []

for linha in arquivo:
    linha = linha.strip('\n')       #Isso vai remover o '\n' do fim da linha
    dados.append(linha.split(' '))  #Isso vai separar os dados
print(*dados,sep='\n')
#output:
# ['1600', '(11/02/2014)', '50', '56', '10', '35', '30', '21', '20', '58']
# ['1610', '(10/03/2014)', '02', '12', '11', '54', '35', '36', '60', '55']
# ['1620', '(20/04/2014)', '40', '15', '12', '17', '25', '51', '38', '24']

#recuperando um dados por exemplo
print('O maior valor de {} e:{}'.format(dados[0][0],dados[0][9]))
```

Outra maneira de tratar isso é criar um dicionario:

```
arquivo = open('jogos.txt', 'r')

    dados = {}
    for linha in arquivo:
        linha = linha.strip('\n')       #Isso vai remover o '\n' do fim da linha
        dados[int(linha[0:4])] = linha[18:].split(' ')
        #converti pra int, lembra que vc esta trabalho com strings
```

O ponto aqui é que eu criei um dicionario para vc acessar os valores atraves do id.
Caso não seja isso que você queira, comenta ai.

Comment: A data vou retirar. O outro exemplo 1600 será o índice.

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta, veja se é isso

Comment: Obrigado é isso mesmo!

Comment: Se der, marca a resposta como solução :)